# Update Azure cloud service package and configuration

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-cloud-services, winnovative

I have a azure cloud service which package and configuration I want to update/re-deploy. I don't find any option in Azure Portal to update the cloud service. Azure classic portal give the option to update the package but I don't have access to that :(

There is no more help of azure documentation except this
[link to deploy cloud service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-create-deploy-portal/)

Is there any way if we can update the package through Azure Portal or VS. 
Actually I have no code I have deploy winnovative html to pdf provided package to cloud service.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to web/worker role cloud services, you must rebuild your service package and re-upload it. The only parts you may update outside of the configuration package:

- the configuration file (`.cscfg`)
- External content stored outside of the package file (such as content you retrieve from blobs)

Answer (score -1):

Cloud Service >> Slot >> "UPDATE"

See here:

[Update cloud service deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYVeW.png)